# Android progress bar does not show

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase for posting the some date and I need to use progress dialog to indicate user while data is being uploaded. I import progress dialog and I need to show it before upload and dismiss after the upload. However the progress dialog does not appear at all.

Can anybody tell me where I am making mistake, thanks.

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


public void postHelp() {

    progressDialog.setMessage("Posting your request...");
    progressDialog.show();

    final String postTitle = title.getText().toString().trim();
    final String postDesc = desc.getText().toString().trim();
    final String postAddress = address.getText().toString().trim();
    final String postPhone = phone.getText().toString().trim();

    //check input fields
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(postTitle) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(postDesc)
            && !TextUtils.isEmpty(postAddress) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(postPhone)) {

        final DatabaseReference newRequest = database.push();
        mDatabaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                newRequest.child("Title").setValue(postTitle);
                newRequest.child("Desc").setValue(postDesc);
                newRequest.child("Address").setValue(postAddress);
                newRequest.child("Phone").setValue(postPhone);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        Intent main = (new Intent(AddPostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(main);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcGV you can find it in android o.O

Comment: post the full code...where are u using `this` in activity?

Answer (score 0):

Call dialog builder like that:

```
AlertDialog.Builder diaog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(okBtn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false)
            ;
```

then

```
dialog.show();
dialog.dismiss();
```